# mod-rewrite not working as expected

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I have this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5&f=$6&g=$7&h=$8&i=$9&j=$10&k=$11&l=$12&m=$13 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5&f=$6&g=$7&h=$8&i=$9&j=$10&k=$11&l=$12 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5&f=$6&g=$7&h=$8&i=$9&j=$10&k=$11 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5&f=$6&g=$7&h=$8&i=$9&j=$10 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5&f=$6&g=$7&h=$8&i=$9 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5&f=$6&g=$7&h=$8 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5&f=$6&g=$7 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5&f=$6 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What it does, is rewrite something like:

> http://www.domain.com/project/backend?a=moderate&b=overview&c=29&d=stoptober&e=page&f=1&g=filter&h=no-twitter&i=no-instagram&j=test&k=test2&l=no-text

to

> http://www.domain.com/project/backend/moderate/overview/29/stoptober/page/1/filter/no-twitter/no-instagram/test/test2/no-text

But when I `var_dump` this, it displays this:

```
array(12) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(8) "moderate"
  ["b"]=>
  string(8) "overview"
  ["c"]=>
  string(2) "29"
  ["d"]=>
  string(9) "stoptober"
  ["e"]=>
  string(4) "page"
  ["f"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["g"]=>
  string(6) "filter"
  ["h"]=>
  string(10) "no-twitter"
  ["i"]=>
  string(12) "no-instagram"
  ["j"]=>
  string(9) "moderate0"
  ["k"]=>
  string(9) "moderate1"
  ["l"]=>
  string(9) "moderate2"
}
```

How is this possible? And more important, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Backreferences` are between `$0` and `$9` included.

If you try `$10` it's the same as `$1` with `0` at the end, which explains `moderate0` (`$1` = `moderate`).

Solution: you need to reduce your params. It is a uri-design problem

---

EDIT: if you want to avoid repeating conditions you can do it as follow

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# all your RewriteRule here
```

Comment: I already thought so after I read your comment, but I read your comment after I created this question

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. this will work the same as you want.. you can change the links name as per your requirements...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?select=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ ?select=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?select=$1&a=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?select=$1&a=$2&b=$3 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?select=$1&a=$2&b=$3&c=$4 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```